# How to Upload Files in a new folder created in a project location?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I am working in a API , where i need to convert Base 64 To image and need to store that image in a location in sever, so that the mobile app can read the path and display the image from there? How to upload files and return the file path like

http://localhost:8080/xxxx.jpg

Note: I am not using any JSP or servlets.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;


def sourceData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAADwCAYAAAA+VemSAAAgAEl...==';

// tokenize the data
def parts = sourceData.tokenize(",");
def imageString = parts[1];

// create a buffered image
BufferedImage image = null;
byte[] imageByte;

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
image = ImageIO.read(bis);
bis.close();
File f = new File("D:\\Image\\Output.jpg");  //output file path
  ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", f);
```